# Gatling scenarios show KOs but specific requests do not

Tags: java, scala, jenkins, report, gatling

After running a Gatling test via Jenkins the report shows that a certain number of requests in different scenarios are failing. However when this is expanded, none of the requests show KOs or give information about which specific requests are failing and why:

[image]

The Gatling logs show 0 sign that there are any errors as well:

[image]

Should I assume that all requests succeeded or is this an issue that needs to be corrected?

EDIT:

I should also mention that I have a run which had 122k reqs and saw a similar issue, however that run also shows 6 reqs which are actually failing and output error messages:

[image]

This leads me to believe that the first picture does not show any real errors, but I am not certain about this.

Answer (score 0):

Random shots in the dark, in the absence of a [reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from you:

- you're forcing the virtual user to a failed state with something like [`Session#markAsFailed`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/#handling-session-state) that would cause the group to fail without any failed request.
- you've configured some of your requests to be [silent](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#silent)

If not, please provide a reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very strange. The best way to double check is to run the same test and enable debug mode.

Also:
you're forcing the virtual user to a failed state with something like Session#markAsFailed that would cause the group to fail without any failed request. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: To run in debug mode do you mean to have this uncommented in the logback.xml file?

     <logger name="io.gatling.http" level="DEBUG" />